# Why is linear time reducible important

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

When proving the lower bound of a new problem by reducing an existing problem of known complexity to it the emphasis is on linear time reduction. I kind of guess that for greater than linear time (say omega n^2 which is greater than linear omega n) we can not compare the two problems. But how to say it formally.

Also, say the known problem is omega n^3. Will now a omega n^2 reduction safely prove that the unknown problem has n^3 complexity?

Comment: `... linear time (say omega n^2)` linear time is not in `Omega(n^2)`. I think you have confused a complexity of the problem (which is Omega) and the complexity of the reduction. Can you please go over the question and clarify?

Comment: are you trying to say `polynomial complexity`?

Comment: Also, reduction is the process to turn a problem into another (or to solve a problem with the solution of another). If you prove that a n^3 problem can be solved by an n^2 algorithm, then the problem wasn't n^3 to begin with.

Comment: @Daniel If you take time `O(n^2)` to reduce a problem to one that can be solved in `O(n^3)` then that solves the original problem in time `O(n^3)`.  Which is, I believe, the case that the poster intended to describe.

Comment: @amit I meant n^2 is not linear. I have changed the sentence to make it clearer. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Daniel what btilly said is what i meant. The question applies for polynomial complexity too. Anyway, the form a.n^b which is polynomial covers both n and n^2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formal statement.

Suppose that problem type A can be solved in time `O(f(n)`.

Suppose that problem B can be reduced in time `O(g(n))` to a problem of size `h(n)`.

Then we can solve problem `B` in time `O(g(n) + f(h(n)))`.

Ideally we want the reduction to be fast and for the problem to not blow up too much.  You generally can't do better than a linear time reduction since it takes linear time just to enter the problem.  That is why that is the ideal.

Note that if `f(n)` has a polynomial upper bound then "a problem of size `h(n)`" can be relaxed to, "a problem of size `O(h(n))`."  This is often true, and saves a lot of effort.  However an example where that kind of simplification fails is with `f(n) = 2^n` and `h(n) = n+log(n))`.

Comment: @rajesh You always get a lower bound.  You just might not get a very *good* lower bound.  Case in point, any problem in NP can be reduced to an NP-complete problem and this gives you a lower bound. But it tends to be a poor one.  However if you've got a SAT solver handy, this may still be a useful thing to try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, basically  O( g(n) + f(h(n)) ) is O(fh(n)) if g(n) has lower order terms than f(h(n)). I got that intuition.
But, the problem is to claim B has a lower bound (equal to A in linear reduction) an instance of A should be reduced to B.

Comment: Sorry. I could not edit my comment after 5mins. So I posted a new one after deleting the old one. I did not see your reply.